# How to use env variable in a tmux bind-key map?

Tags: tmux

I want my bind-key command to make use of a variable.

Here is my .tmux.conf file:

```
# .tmux.conf
bind-key r rename-session $MY_VARIABLE
```

How can I set MY_VARIABLE on a session-by-session basis?

#### Things I have tried that did not work:

- Run `export MY_VARIABLE=my_value` in bash before pressing `C-b r`.
- Run `tmux setenv MY_VARIABLE my_value` in bash before pressing `C-b r`.

(`C-b` is my prefix in tmux)

#### The following (based on [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/369034/how-can-i-set-custom-variables-in-tmux)) DOES WORK:

Add a line to to .tmux.conf, like this:

```
# .tmux.conf
MY_VARIABLE=my_value
bind-key r rename-session $MY_VARIABLE
```

Running `C-b r` the successfully renames the session. But this is less than ideal, because `MY_VARIABLE=my_value` is hard-coded into the .tmux.conf file; I want a way to change MY_VARIABLE on an ad-hoc basis.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Typically, the way round this is to go through the shell again, eg:

```
bind-key r run-shell 'tmux rename-session "$MY_VARIABLE"'
```

The single quotes stops the variable from being expanding whilst parsing the config file. If you then later say

```
tmux setenv MY_VARIABLE my_value
```

it will set the session environment.
When you then type prefix-`r` the shell forked by `run-shell` will inherit these session variables, and the shell will be able to replace the variable by the current value for the session.